# Force a re-render of React Native Google Mobile Ads Banner component. (react-native-google-mobile-ads)

Tags: react-native, admob, banner-ads, react-native-google-mobile-ads

I am using `react-native-google-mobile-ads` in a `@shopify/flash-list` list, and it functions as expected except the nature of flash-list is recycling the ad banner component over and over again as it's supposed to. The ad never changes. The React Native Google Mobile Ads docs say "**to reload/change an advert for a currently mounted component, you'll need to force a re-render...**"

Any ideas on how to do this?

[React Native Google Mobile Ads Banner Ads Docs](https://docs.page/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads/displaying-ads#banner-ads-component)

```
import React from 'react';
import { BannerAd, BannerAdSize, TestIds } from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads';

const adUnitId = __DEV__ ? TestIds.BANNER : 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyyyyyyy';

function AdmobListAd({ keywordsArr }) {
  return (
    <BannerAd
      unitId={adUnitId}
      size={BannerAdSize.ANCHORED_ADAPTIVE_BANNER}
      requestOptions={{
        requestNonPersonalizedAdsOnly: true,
        keywords: keywordsArr 
      }}
    />
  );
}

export default AdmobListAd;
```

Comment: Hey @cory, did you figure this out? I have the same doubt!
Thanks!

Comment: I think this can be achieved with [hooks](https://docs.page/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads/displaying-ads-hook#show-the-ad) and passing `index` of the list as dependency.